# Mean of a Row in Python (Reading CSV files using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am completely new to python.. I would like to ask how can I fix my code?

I can't make it to work because for some reason, it only calculates columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rainfall = pd.read_csv('rainfall.csv', low_memory=False, parse_dates=True, header=None)
mean_rainfall = rainfall[0].mean()
print(mean_rainfall)
```

[the picture of my csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU1Lo.png)

Comment: Please restructure your question according to the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In pandas dataframe mean function you can provide parameter to let him him know either take mean of a row or column.
Check Here: [pandas.DataFrame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).
It seams though it takes default axis value of 1 so it is calculation the mean of column.
Try this:

```
mean_rainfall = rainfall.iloc[0].mean(axis = 1)
```

Comment: It seems that problem is with the way you are trying to extract first row. Try using dataframe.iloc 
In your case use this: rainfall.iloc[0].mean(axis = 1)
Let me know if this works.